# Can we track system logging and system logout time in R shiny

Tags: r

For the purpose of tracking my application, I have incorporated logging events in my application. It is tracking all information. But I need to put app opening time and opp closing time. Is it possible to achieve this?

For app opening time, I have used `Sys.time()`

I tried with below but did not work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session$onSessionEnded`

```
session$onSessionEnded(function(needed_parameters) {
    #save logs
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I use  ````log_value(Sys.time())````  to track login time. Now should I try a function  like below to track logout time                                          
  ```` users_data <- data.frame(START = Sys.time())
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    users_data$END <- Sys.time()
  })````

Comment: You have to create the dataframe with `Sys.time()` in the server code first, then save logs inside `onSessionEnded` with the new current time.

Comment: Sorry. Can you help me with the code. I am not getting it :(

Comment: In the begining of server store only `START` in `user_data`. Then save your file inside the function `onSessionEnded` by adding `END` column to `user_data`.

Comment: Yeah. I did, But I am getting error as "Session not found"

Comment: You have to add it in `shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {`

Comment: Add `session` argument in `shinyServer` and it should work

Comment: I have added..........but no luck :( I have attached a picture in the question please check